# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this button code in ASP.NET MVC 5.

In the browser I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

```
<input type="button" value="Bid for this project" 
       onclick="location.href'@Url.Action("Create", "Bid", new {projectid = Model.ProjectID})'" />
```

In browser, button looks like this :

```
<input type="button" value="Bid for this project" 
       onclick="location.href'/Bid/Create?projectid=1'" />
```

Can you tell me how to make this right? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is missing the assignment operator `=` after the `href`:

```
<input type="button" value="Bid for this project" 
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Bid", new {projectid = Model.ProjectID})'" />
```

In browser:

```
<input type="button" value="Bid for this project" onclick="location.href='/Bid/Create?projectid=1'" />
```

It should work after you add it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `=` sign

```
<input type="button" value="Bid for this project" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Bid", new {projectid = Model.ProjectID})'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed  `=` after `href`

```
<input type="button" value="Bid for this project" onclick="location.href= '@Url.Action("Create", "Bid", new {projectid = Model.ProjectID})'" />
```

As the correct javascript syntax is

```
location.href= '@Url.Action("Create", "Bid", new {projectid = Model.ProjectID})';
```